# STM32F107 CAN software driver does not work

Tags: stm32, c, can, keil

I am using ST drivers to use CAN bus on an STM22F107 according to the code below. It does not work. The code is as below and is available [here](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Driver/html/group__can__interface__gr.html).

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "cmsis_os.h"
 
    #include "Driver_CAN.h"
 
    // CAN Driver Controller selector
    #define  CAN_CONTROLLER         1       // CAN Controller number
 
    #define _CAN_Driver_(n)         Driver_CAN##n
    #define  CAN_Driver_(n)        _CAN_Driver_(n)
    extern   ARM_DRIVER_CAN         CAN_Driver_(CAN_CONTROLLER);
    #define  ptrCAN               (&CAN_Driver_(CAN_CONTROLLER))
 
    uint32_t                        rx_obj_idx  = 0xFFFFFFFFU;
    uint8_t                         rx_data[8];
    ARM_CAN_MSG_INFO                rx_msg_info;
    uint32_t                        tx_obj_idx  = 0xFFFFFFFFU;
    uint8_t                         tx_data[8];
    ARM_CAN_MSG_INFO                tx_msg_info;
 
    static void Error_Handler (void) { while (1); }
 
    void CAN_SignalUnitEvent (uint32_t event) {}
 
    void CAN_SignalObjectEvent (uint32_t obj_idx, uint32_t event) {
 
      if (obj_idx == rx_obj_idx) {                  // If receive object event
    if (event == ARM_CAN_EVENT_RECEIVE) {       // If message was received successfully
      if (ptrCAN->MessageRead(rx_obj_idx, &rx_msg_info, rx_data, 8U) > 0U) {
                                                // Read received message
        // process received message ...
      }
    }
  }
    if (obj_idx == tx_obj_idx) {                  // If transmit object 
         event
            if (event == ARM_CAN_EVENT_SEND_COMPLETE) { // If message was sent 
    successfully
          // acknowledge sent message ...
        }
      }
    }
 
int main (void) {
  ARM_CAN_CAPABILITIES     can_cap;
  ARM_CAN_OBJ_CAPABILITIES can_obj_cap;
  int32_t                  status;
  uint32_t                 i, num_objects;
 
  can_cap = ptrCAN->GetCapabilities (); // Get CAN driver capabilities
  num_objects = can_cap.num_objects;    // Number of receive/transmit objects
 
  status = ptrCAN->Initialize    (CAN_SignalUnitEvent, CAN_SignalObjectEvent);  // Initialize CAN driver
  if (status != ARM_DRIVER_OK ) { Error_Handler(); }
 
  status = ptrCAN->PowerControl  (ARM_POWER_FULL);                              // Power-up CAN controller
  if (status != ARM_DRIVER_OK ) { Error_Handler(); }
 
  status = ptrCAN->SetMode       (ARM_CAN_MODE_INITIALIZATION);                 // Activate initialization mode
  if (status != ARM_DRIVER_OK ) { Error_Handler(); }
 
  status = ptrCAN->SetBitrate    (ARM_CAN_BITRATE_NOMINAL,              // Set nominal bitrate
                                  100000U,                              // Set bitrate to 100 kbit/s
                                  ARM_CAN_BIT_PROP_SEG(5U)   |          // Set propagation segment to 5 time quanta
                                  ARM_CAN_BIT_PHASE_SEG1(1U) |          // Set phase segment 1 to 1 time quantum (sample point at 87.5% of bit time)
                                  ARM_CAN_BIT_PHASE_SEG2(1U) |          // Set phase segment 2 to 1 time quantum (total bit is 8 time quanta long)
                                  ARM_CAN_BIT_SJW(1U));                 // Resynchronization jump width is same as phase segment 2
  if (status != ARM_DRIVER_OK ) { Error_Handler(); }
 
  for (i = 0U; i < num_objects; i++) {                                          // Find first available object for receive and transmit
    can_obj_cap = ptrCAN->ObjectGetCapabilities (i);                            // Get object capabilities
    if      ((rx_obj_idx == 0xFFFFFFFFU) && (can_obj_cap.rx == 1U)) { rx_obj_idx = i; }
    else if ((tx_obj_idx == 0xFFFFFFFFU) && (can_obj_cap.tx == 1U)) { tx_obj_idx = i; break; }
  }
  if ((rx_obj_idx == 0xFFFFFFFFU) || (tx_obj_idx == 0xFFFFFFFFU)) { Error_Handler(); }
 
  // Set filter to receive messages with extended ID 0x12345678 to receive object
  status = ptrCAN->ObjectSetFilter(rx_obj_idx, ARM_CAN_FILTER_ID_EXACT_ADD, ARM_CAN_EXTENDED_ID(0x12345678U), 0U);
  if (status != ARM_DRIVER_OK ) { Error_Handler(); }
 
  status = ptrCAN->ObjectConfigure(tx_obj_idx, ARM_CAN_OBJ_TX);                 // Configure transmit object
  if (status != ARM_DRIVER_OK ) { Error_Handler(); }
 
  status = ptrCAN->ObjectConfigure(rx_obj_idx, ARM_CAN_OBJ_RX);                 // Configure receive object
  if (status != ARM_DRIVER_OK ) { Error_Handler(); }
  
  status = ptrCAN->SetMode (ARM_CAN_MODE_NORMAL);                               // Activate normal operation mode
  if (status != ARM_DRIVER_OK ) { Error_Handler(); }
  
  memset(&tx_msg_info, 0U, sizeof(ARM_CAN_MSG_INFO));                           // Clear message info structure
  tx_msg_info.id = ARM_CAN_EXTENDED_ID(0x12345678U);                            // Set extended ID for transmit message
  tx_data[0]     = 0xFFU;                                                       // Initialize transmit data
  while (1) {
    tx_data[0]++;                                                               // Increment transmit data
    status = ptrCAN->MessageSend(tx_obj_idx, &tx_msg_info, tx_data, 1U);        // Send data message with 1 data byte
    if (status != 1U) { Error_Handler(); }
    for (i = 0U; i < 1000000U; i++) { __nop(); }                                // Wait a little while
  }
}
```

Register settings in debug are as follows:
[image]

Edit: It seems that the error is "**Bit dominant Error**". I do not the root cause of it.
Can you could help me to find the problem?

Comment: What does "not works" mean? What does it do and what do you you expect it to do?

Comment: @Justme Thanks for the comment. Both CAN_L and H are 2.5 V. In addition stm32 does not send any serial data to CAN transceiver.

Comment: Do you use any libraries? Or only CMSIS and objects/structs you create from it? Did you go into debugging and check in SFR if all related registers have correct configuration bits? Is the peripheral clock activated? (I forgot the clock so many times; pls answer each of these questions). You best add this info into the question, not in the comments here

Comment: @Ilya Thanks for the comment. I use CMSIS, and corresponding configs are exactly based on an official example for CAN. I also use GPIO in the project which works and therefore clock is OK.

Comment: @user15847 did you activate the clock of CAN specifically? GPIO clock and CAN clock are two totally indepent things. Did you check the contents of CAN configuration registers after you do the setup? Please **add detailed answers to this to the question**

Comment: @Ilya I think all peripherals are fed by a common clock. I have not checked them. I will check.

Comment: @user15847 you're very wrong about that. Each individual peripheral you use has to have its clock activated individually. Every single one. Every single GPIO port has its own clock activation too (for CAN to work you need to activate clock of CAN and clock of GPIO port, whose pins will work as CAN). If you check the CAN configuration registers and read all zeros in all registers, it means your CAN clock is off, for instance.

Comment: Also, you're deliberately ignoring much more important question. What's the content of CAN registers when you complete the setup? Set breakpoint after you do setup but before you send anything, do "debugging", and when you stop at the breakpoint, open Special Function Registers, find your CAN and check what the content of CAN registers is. It will almost certainly direct you to solving the problem.

Comment: @Ilya checked and added image of registers. It seems it is OK!

Comment: Great! Two things: 1) clock for CAN is definitely activated and 2) Open your MCU reference manual, scroll down to CAN registers and check what each bit there means. Make sure every setting matches what you want it to be. For example, in MSR register, the "C" part of the value says that "transmit" mode is off and "receive" mode is also off. I don't know if it's expected behavior. https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00171190-stm32f101xx-stm32f102xx-stm32f103xx-stm32f105xx-and-stm32f107xx-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf page 676

Comment: @Ilya After transmit, ERRI is set 1 which means there is an error. And according to ESR register, the error is "Bit dominant Error".

Comment: Great job! You're getting a hang of it. You will probably have to read the entire CAN section of the reference manual, it explains all the stuff that must be set up and everything that can happen and what and why error flags are thrown. I'm afraid I can't help you further, I've never used CAN in my life. But it's all about approach. Keep digging what's wrong or what's missing and why, why the error flag is there. You're on the right path. If you find something relevant, edit it into the post. You may want to edit that bit about ERRI into the post, it crucially narrows down the problem.

Comment: "Bit dominant error" is some ST term for "your CAN bus is toast". It tried to drive the bus to the dominant level but failed. I'd recommend reading this next: [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251)

Comment: Although if you have indeed verified with your scope that absolutely nothing comes out of CAN Tx towards the transceiver, then the problem must be related to incorrect port routing, incorrect use of pull resistors, or bad soldering.

Comment: Unrelated to that problem, the `SetBitrate` call looks strange. Where did you get those tq values from? Many controllers expect you to write a value one lower than the actual tq and iirc that's also the case with ST. For 87.5% sample point you should then have 1 tq sync, 11 tq prop seg, 2 tq phase seg1, 2 tq phase seg2. Values to write to the register ought to be `ARM_CAN_BIT_PROP_SEG(10), ARM_CAN_BIT_PHASE_SEG1(1), ARM_CAN_BIT_PHASE_SEG2(1)` and your comments in the C source seem wrong.

Comment: @Lundin I have set this values based on an example of at ST. With changing values nothing happened.

Comment: As I said, incorrect baudrate settings aren't related to not getting anything out of the tx pin at all. It could only be one of the problems I mentioned, unless you've managed to disable the whole CAN controller or fail to clock it etc.